# Set default value of dropdown in Angular 6

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular7

I am populating DropDown using service. service returns simple Array of key/value pair.

**TypeScript:**

```
public initializeForm(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            supplierId: ["", [Validators.required]],
            username: ["", Validators.required],
            credentials: ["", [Validators.required]],
            rating: [""]
        })
    }


this.adminService.getSuppliers({ active: "true" }).subscribe(res => {
    this.suppliers = res;
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="supplierId">
     <option>Select Supplier</option>
     <option *ngFor="let s of suppliers" [value]="s.supplierId">{{s.supplierName}}</option>
</select>
```

> As you can see in below image, default option is not set as selected
>   option on page load. I want default option to be selected on page load same like simple HTML and fires required field validation when I try to submit page by selecting default option in dropdown

[image]

**UPDATED:**
If i set default option value to 0, it doesn't support required validation and consider as valid if I select default option

Comment: What image? What is not working?

Comment: @ritaj - sorry I missed image, I've again updated my question

Comment: You can try this [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set validation.min with required as well like below one.

```
supplierId: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]]
```

> supplierId is always greater zero so min(1) works for you.

Comment: yes, by combination of yes, by combination of <option value="">Select Supplier</option> and [validators.min(1)] its working. I don't need to set any extra variable in TS file to get Selected option show by default on page load.

Comment: Also, I think I don't require validatiors.required as well, do I?

Comment: supplierId: ["DEFAULT VALUE OF THE DROPDOWN", [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]]

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the value from `formControlName`

here is the example

```
this.myFormGroup.setValue({
  supplierId: myValue1, 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="someList.key" name="key"  #key="ngModel" required>
     <option value="undefined" selected disabled>Select option</option>
     <option *ngFor="let data of someList" value="{{data.key}}">{{data.key}</option>
 </select>
```

Worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

You can set it by `setValue`

```
ngOnInit(){
   let defaultId = 1;
   this.yourForm.controls['supplierId'].setValue(defaultId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Worked for me.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="supplierId">
  <option [ngValue]="selected" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
 <option *ngFor="llet s of suppliers" [ngValue]="s.supplierId">{{s.supplierName}} 
</option>
```

Comment: In TS set  default value as `selected`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
<option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a default value as `0` for the default option. (0 is juts an example, you can have any default value)

```
<option value="0">Select Supplier</option>
```

When you create the form control for the dropdown initialize it with the default value.

```
// wharever your form name is, this is just an example
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({  
    .....
    supplierId: [0]  // initialize the control with the default value
    ....
})
```

Comment: I've updated my question, If i set value of default option to 0, required field validation not works if i select default option

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers you can follow @Paresh's suggestion or you can set the default option like: `<option value="">Select Supplier</option>` and your control like: `supplierId: ["", [Validators.required]],`

Comment: yes, by combination of  <option value="">Select Supplier</option> and [validators.min(1)] its working

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Doesn't it work withut the `min(1)` validator? since your aren't setting any value by default. Its an empty string

Comment: if I don't set any value, it takes 0 by default, so min(1) works

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers: That's not true, or should not be true, you are initializing the form control with an empty string why will take `0` by default?

Answer (score 0):

Include below code on your component.html file

```
  <option [value] = "defaultValue">0:(optional_value)</option>
```

Include below code on your component.ts file.

```
this.myFormGroup.setValue({
supplierId: defaultValue, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set the value as below, where `suppliers` is any array of dropdown values and suppliers [0] is the default value, which will be already selected.

```
    this.form.patchValue({
      supplierId: this.suppliers[0], 
    });
```