# Angular dropdown validation when the default value is set to '0'

Tags: html, angular, validation, dropdown, angular-ng-if

I have set default value  for 'Select' as '0' for my dropdown.

Validation Rules

1.Make the selection of dropdown as required.(Atleast select one option from the dropdown).

2.If a value is not selected, then show an error saying that "You need to select an option"

Things I have tried:

Case 1:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="plain-select">
                <select class="form-control" id="select101" formControlName="UserId"
                  [(ngModel)]="editFormData.userId">
                  *****<option value='0' selected>Select</option>*****
                  <option *ngFor="let user of usernames" value={{user.userId}}>
                    {{user.usernames}}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <div
                *ngIf="addUserForm.controls['UserId'].invalid && (submited || ` addUserForm.controls['UserId'].dirty || addUserForm.controls['UserId'].touched)"`
                class="error-msg">
                <div *ngIf="addUserForm.controls['UserId'].errors.required">
                  UserId is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
      
      TypeScript:
      
        UserId:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
```

**In the above case:

```
        I am able to see the default as "Select" but the validation doesn't work.
```

It doesn't give any validation error when no option is selected from the dropdown.

Case-2 :

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="plain-select">
                <select class="form-control" id="select101" formControlName="UserId"
                  [(ngModel)]="editFormData.UserId">
                  <option value='null' selected>Select</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let user of usernames" value={{user.userId}}>
                    {{user.usernames}}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <div
                *ngIf="addUserForm.controls['UserId'].invalid && (submited || addUserForm.controls['UserId'].dirty || addUserForm.controls['UserId'].touched)"
                class="error-msg">
                <div *ngIf="addUserForm.controls['UserId'].errors.required">
                  UserId is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
      
        TypeScript:
      
      

  UserId:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
        
        In the above case, the validation is working as expected but however the default value is not set to "Select" and also the validation works only if "Select" option is selected from the dropdown
        
        Case-3:
        
        Same happens when i select the value to "undefined".
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to make it work is to use `ngValue` for data binding

```
  <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of usernames" [ngValue]="user.userId">
    {{user.username}} - {{user.userId}}
  </option>
```

To show validation error (note the `?.` [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)):

```
  <div *ngIf="frm.controls['UserId'].dirty && frm.controls['UserId']?.errors?.required">
    UserId is required.
  </div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sgjhzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.

In my case however, I cannot use [ngValue] = "null" since my userId doesn't accept null values.
If I use  [ngValue] = "null" in my case, the 'Select' value isn't rendered. The dropdown default value is empty.
However, the validation works when i choose the option of Select from the Dropdown.

2. If the bind [ngValue] = 0, the default option is loaded but the validations doesn't work.


If we replace, [ngValue] = "null" with [ngValue]=0 in the above Demo. The exact scenario is happening in my case when I bind the [ngValue] with"null".

Comment: Trying to implement something like this, but it doesn't work in my case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037515/set-default-value-of-dropdown-in-angular-6

Comment: @rutuja Please create a Stackblitz